# "the doctor" vs. "the doctor's"

Tags: word-usage

[From the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20doctor)

> I saw her at **the doctor's** last week.

> How long will you be at **the doctor**?

Considering the fact that both of them come from the Merriam-Webster dictionary, it seems sure that both "the doctor" and "the doctor's" are grammatically correct.

However, [the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/doctor) just lists the former. Does that means the latter is not as popular nowadays?

Comment: This is discussed at ["Is It 'Doctor's Appointment' or 'Doctor Appointment'?"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/is-it-doctors-appointment-or-doctor-appointment) which is also at Merriam-Webster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the name of an occupation, the possessive indicates 'that person's place of work' - it implies *the doctor's surgery (office* in American English).

Don't forget that Cambridge is a British dictionary and Merriam-Webster is American. Presumably *at the doctor* is also idiomatic in American English

Comment: Thank you. Presumably, "is at the doctor's" means someone is seeing a doctor, right?

Comment: Usually, yes. ('I saw her at the doctor's' could possibly refer to someone who had accompanied the patient there.)