# "just gives one option" vs. "gives just one option"

Tags: adverbs

There are two options A and B regarding to the usage of a word in the Merriam-Webster dictionary while the Cambridge Dictionary **just** gives one, that is A.

To convey that idea, should I say

> the Cambridge Dictionary **just gives one option**

or

> the Cambridge Dictionary **gives just one option**

Where should I put the adverb "just" and why?

---

The context is adapted from the post ["the doctor" vs. "the doctor's"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/251396/116345)

Comment: This sense of _just_ means _only_, and goes in the same niches, which is to say that it may appear immediately before the lexical item that is its [focus (and is ordinarily stressed)](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55314/15299), **or** it may go immediately before any constituent that contains its focus. That means both A and B are grammatical and have the same meaning. In print, of course, all sentences are multiply ambiguous because stress is not represented, so the closer one puts focussing operators like _only_ or _even_ to their focus element, the less ambiguity one invokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In normal speech, I would say A.

This is formally ambiguous, (but not in practice). But in writing, I might prefer B, which avoids the ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you. Does "formally" here mean "seemingly"?

Comment: No. It means that just looking at the form (or shape) of the sentence, it could be ambiguous, as the _just_ could apply to diffiernt parts of it.